# Firebase same file different download urls

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I'm using Firebase for images storage. However, I find after I upload the image, the image name will keep the same name as on the local device. It means that, if I upload two images with the same name, the previous one will be replaced. Is there a default Firebase method can automatically generate image name and keep them both? Or should I generate unique image name by myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37444839/5036979), It was left for the developer to specify the file name, firebase will not handle it for you.