# Different Image names

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, firebase-storage

I started working with Firebase in my iOS App. I am trying to upload images to Firebase Storage. Fortunately, I was able to upload images to Firebase Storage using Swift 3. My issue is I always need to specify the name of the image in coding.

For e.g.:

```
let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL:
gs://my_app_name.appspot.com/").child("images/new.jpg")
```

Here, `new.jpg` is the image name. If I try to upload images multiple times, it gets replaced by the new image but the name remains the same. As a result I always get 1 item in my image folder.

All the example I have seen is for uploading for a single image. In my case the user can upload multiple images.

Is there any method or way so that every time I upload an image to Firebase it gets uploaded with a different image name. Or can I get the name of the image from the iPhone simulator?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can give the file any name you want. For example, this question asks for a random filename: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444685/store-files-with-unique-random-names

Comment: Have you considered making use of timestamps as the default name to avoid duplicates?

Comment: No I haven't used the concept of timestamps..

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer that I would like to share. Hope it may help others.

1. UUID

```
let imageUniqueName = UUID().uuidString

let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL:
gs://my_app_name.appspot.com/").child("images/\\(imageUniqueName)")
```

Note: `\\(imageUniqueName)` can be called with string interpolation

2. Or

   a) Create a textfield in which the user can give the name of the image he is going to upload while uploading.

   b) store the value of the textfield in a variable.

   c) enter the variable name using above method (String interpolation)

For example:

```
@IBOutlet weak var imageName: UITextField!

let Name = (imageName?.text)!

let storage = FIRStorage.storage().reference(forURL:
gs://my_app_name.appspot.com/").child("images/\\(Name)")
```