# Image is deleted after user post another

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-storage

I am using firebase storage, a user publishes a photo and this happens without problems. When the same user publishes one more photo, the first one is deleted.

Need to set some rules?

Cutting some pieces my storage code looks like this:

```
var metadata = { contentType: fileObject.type };
                var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
                var uploadFile = storageRef.child(folder + '/' + filename).put(fileObject, metadata);
   uploadFile.on(firebase.storage.TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED,
        function (snapshot) {
        var progress = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;
        $timeout(function () {
        progressFn(progress);
        console.log(progress);
    });
},
```

Comment: If you upload a file to the same location/path it will overwrite any existing fle at that location/path. So you will need to ensure that the files you upload have a unique name on the server. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444685/store-files-with-unique-random-names

Comment: Thank you, it helped me to clarify